# PDF creation and text formatting

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, formatting

Question about text formatting when creating a PDF programmatically on the iPhone.

I have a formatted `NSString` with Tabs `(\t)` in it. On the debugging output it looks perfect and fine, but when this strings is used to generate a PDF, the Tabs are gone and replaced by a single space.. Any idea?

( Tried a font like Courier, no luck, also the page boundary is big enough, there is more then enough room to display the text)

This is the code I use to make the PDF:

```
- (void)drawStuffInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10];

    CGRect textRect = CGRectInset(kPDFPageBounds, 36, 36);
    [textHolder drawInRect:textRect withFont:font];

}
```

Comment: What tool/programming language did you use to convert your string/text to PDF???

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear in describing what exactly you're doing.

But the first thing I would try is this:

- Replace your tabs with spaces yourself -- use as many spaces for each tab as make you happy.
- Then convert this new string/text to PDF.

Comment: well its very straight forward. I have this NSString:           textHolder = @"\nDate\t\tRegistration\tFlight #\tDeparture\tOff Block\tAirborne\tLanding\t\tOn Block\tArrival\t\tPassengers\tTotal Flight Time\tTotal Block Time\n\n";         And it turns the tabs (\t) to spaces when creating the PDF. Obviously I need the tabs because of the layout, spaces is not an option..

Comment: @martin010: Tabs not "printable" characters, spaces are. That's why you can set up text editors to fake the tab 'length' to match a certain number of spaces. So you *have* to decided how many spaces should replace your each of `\t`.

Comment: Got that. But doesn't that mess up the alignment when using non fixed-witdh fonts like Arial?  If you then use spaces, stuff will not be lined out correctly?

Comment: Of course it does mess up alignment. 'Tabstops' in a word processor or on a typewriter are different kind of cattle than 'TAB' character (ASCII byte #9) used in a text editor.... (Tabstop: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop -- Tab char: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_character)